# How can I create a Data Policy for the Play Store for a Unity Game?

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console, unityads

I have a small Quiz App pusblished on the Play Store.
But since published a lot of stuff changed and now I need to provide a Data Policy.

The Quiz uses the Unity Ads SDK and uses Google Play Achievments and leaderboards, apart from that it saves the progress the player has made only locally on the device, so that should not matter to Data Security. You can't sign in to the game or anything, apart from the Google Play Stuff itself.

The Data Policy needs to be hosted on my domain, which is not the problem, but no matter what I create as a Data Policy, it always gets rejected by Google Play.

Does anybody know where I can find a template or an example of a Data Policy fitting for my App?

Edit: I also have problems with the form on the Google Play Console about Data Savety.